# Google Charts and Ajax Response's

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have been working on this for quite some time. And I cannot seem to figure out why I cannot populate my charts.  I am using the google charts api. When I pass the data to

```
new google.visualization.DataTable(getData(playWithData))
```

it returns "Table Has No Columns".

This is my current ajax call to my controller

```
function getData(callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/lead_sources',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
      callback(data);
    })
  }

  function playWithData(data){
    console.log(data);
  }

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(getData(playWithData))
```

Inside the console [image]

Currently I am using dummy data from my controller to get the ajax call to work properly. Formatting similar to the DOCUMENTATION https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

```
{
      cols: [{label: 'Week', type: 'string'},
             {label: 'Facebook', type: 'number'},
             {label: 'Twitter', type: 'number'},
             {label: 'Instagram', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [{c:[{v: 'Week 1'},
                 {v: 5,  f: 'Five'},
                 {v: 12, f: 'Twelve'},
                 {v: 4, f: 'Four'}
            ]}
      ]
    }
```

Im not sure if I am missing something or I am doing something completely wrong. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a combination of async logic executing in a manner you're not anticipating, and the fact that neither of your functions returns any data.

You need to create the `DataTable` in the callback function itself, once the `data` has been retrieved. Try this:

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/lead_sources',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
        // amend settings of dataTable here, as needed

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(dataTable, { showRowNumber: true });
    })
}

getData(); // call when required
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have got something showing up on my charts now!! Spent so much time trying a million different things. Thanks!